# reader vs buffered reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

what would be the performance difference on calling `read(char[] cbuf)` between `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` assuming the size of the buffer for `BufferedReader` to be the same as `cbuf`.

I know that a simple `read()` call on the `FileReader` is slower sice every time a native call is being made to read each character.

A `read(char[] cbuf)` on the `FileReader` would read `cbuf` size of chars with just one native call which is similar to that of the `BufferedReader`.

So would there be any performance difference if `read(char[] cbuf)` method is being used on `FileReader` vs `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Have you tried measuring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A read(char[] cbuf) on the FileReader would read cbuf size of chars with just one native call which is similar to that of the BufferedReader.

That's not correct. There are no native calls that read into Java `char[]` arrays. A FileReader is really an `InputStreamReader` layered over a `FileInputStream.` The `InputStreamReader` runs an 8k internal buffer. So the file is being read up to 8k at a time.

> So would there be any performance difference if read(char[] cbuf) method is being used on `FileReader` vs `BufferedReader`.

You will read opinions that the `BufferedReader` is slower reading into a buffer due to double buffering, but they are not correct. `BufferedReader` detects this case and does the reads directly where possible.

In short, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Buffering twice. BufferedReader has an internal buffer, and the char[] you are reading into is another one.

Answer (score 1):

The plan: BufferedReader consumes some space so typical uses can consume less time.

But measure it, because the performance results depend on such matters as:

- the sizes, timing, and *positions* of read operations (what if each read does a seek just past the buffer length?);
- the computing hardware, native software, and JVM;
- whether you can generally predict those for your application;
- and (in order to get
  benefits of JIT compilation and other runtime optimizations) whether
  your read operations are predictable or not, bursty or sustained.

Furthermore the significance of the performance results will depend on the functional requirements of your application.

You didn't mention concerns for maintaining the software, but generally that's worth considering as a major part of the lifetime cost of software. It's easier to maintain code that uses the standard library than code that reinvents the same functionality.